# Set agent pool conditionally

Tags: azure-pipelines

Is it possible to set the pool conditionally?

Something like this?

```
jobs:
- job: 'The_job'
  pool:
    ${{ if or( eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'), gt(variables['Build.BuildId'], '8')) }}:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest' # Always build master on the MS hosted pool (limited to 1800 hours per month).
    ${{ else }}:
      name: 'Default'
```

The condition on `Build.SourceBranchName` works but the condition on `Build.BuildId` does not.

Comment: Do you have it in template?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not think this is possible using `Build.BuildId`.

I ran a bunch of tests to try and figure this out.

First off, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#gt) for gt/ge/lt/le: `Converts right parameter to match type of left parameter. Errors if conversion fails`.

Given that, we are going to want the second parameter to be the variable reference. However, this does not solve your problem.

I tested this with two varaibles, `Build.BuildId` and `System.DefinitionId`. BuildId is not available in templates, whilst DefinitionId is. This can be seen in the [Predefiend variables docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in the column `Available in templates?`

---

Test 1 (not working):

```
  ${{ if lt(8, variables['Build.BuildId']) }}:
    var: 1
  ${{ else }}:
    var: 2

jobs:
- job: 'Compare'
  steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Print values'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo $(var)
            echo $(Build.BuildId)
```

[image]

---

Test two (working, but not the variable you want):

```
variables:
  ${{ if lt(8, variables['System.DefinitionId']) }}:
    var: 1
  ${{ else }}:
    var: 2

jobs:
- job: 'Compare'
  steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Print values'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo $(var)
            echo $(System.DefinitionId)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The condition on Build.SourceBranchName works but the condition on Build.BuildId does not.

This is because `if expression` is expanded at `compile` time, if you use the variable inside, need to make sure it can get the value.

As per the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) doc(check the last column `Available in templates?` value), for`Build.SourceBranchName`, it can get the value at compile time:
[image]

But for `Build.BuildId` value, it's `No`.
[image]

You need to choose another predefined variable(last column value is Yes) in the if expression. eg:

```
jobs:
- job: 'The_job'
  pool:
    ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual')) }}:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest' # Always build master on the MS hosted pool (limited to 1800 hours per month).
    ${{ else }}:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
```

If you would like to use `Build.BuildId` or other `No`(`Available in templates?` value) variable, you can use in `condition` instead of if expression.

```
- job: 'The_job'
  condition: or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'), eq(variables['Build.BuildId'], '2904'))
  pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest' # Always build master on the MS hosted pool (limited to 1800 hours per month).
  steps:
    - script: echo test
```

Please note i changed to `eq` expression here, as the expression(gt,lt...) treat the buildid as string format, cannot simply compare the value with 8. In above, it's recommended to change another variable for the condition/if expression.